# How to wrap JSX elements in a React.ReactNode variable

Tags: reactjs

I have a React.ReactNode variable (which can be passed as props)

```
export default function App() {
  const MyButton = <Button size='large'/>
  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton>Click here</MyButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But this code doesn't work - I'm getting the error: `JSX element does not have any construct or call signatures`

What I'm trying to do, in other words, I would like to take the MyButton variable, and inject children into it. How can I do that?

I tried with React.createElement:

```
{React.createElement(
  MyButton,
  {},
  <div>
    <p>Child element 1</p>
    <p>Child element 2</p>
  </div>
)}
```

But it doesn't expect a React.ReactNode as type.

**The real use case I'm trying to implement:**
I'm using the package @react-pdf/renderer, which has a component with which you can wrap a button for example, and then clicking on that button will generate PDF.

In my composition I'm trying to implement it by using two separate components, one that passes the PDF generator component of a PDF library (in this example, react-pdf renderer), and another component, that doesn't know about which library is being used. The second component will use get the PDF generator component and just wrap it around a button.

First component:

```
import { PDFDownloadLink } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

export default function FirstComponent() {
  return (
    <SecondComponent
      {...props}
      downloadPdfElement={
        <PDFDownloadLink
          document={<MyPdfDoc pdfTimelineRows={pdfTimelineRows} />}
          fileName="pdf"
        />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

The second component should just uses the prop `downloadPdfElement` and wrap it around some button.

Again, this can all easily be done in one component, just wrap the PDFDownloadLink around a button and that's it, but I'd like to make it into two separate components. If it's too complex to achieve then it's also an answer

Comment: Your button component should render `props.children`

Comment: I want to use this structure for specific reasons please, in my code it's not my button I'm using but a third party package

Comment: What package are you using for the button?

Comment: It's React pdf renderer, it really doesn't matter for this question

Comment: It really does, The button needs to implement that.

Comment: You're trying to use an _element_ as a _component_.

Comment: btw, using this package? https://react-pdf.org/components Can't find a button compont tho

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, I'd suggest defining a new component, that will wrap `props.children` in a `PDFDownloadLink`, that way you can call that wrapper component anytime, and render a `PDFDownloadLink` with some custom props.

The `DownloadWrapper` can be extended to add more props to fit your needs.

```js
// Demo, imported from Lib
const PDFDownloadLink = (props) => {
    return <button>{props.children}</button>;
}

// Wrapper download button
const DownloadWrapper = (props) => {
    return <PDFDownloadLink>{props.children}</PDFDownloadLink>;
}

const Example = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <DownloadWrapper>
                <div>
                    <p>Child element 1</p>
                    <p>Child element 2</p>
                </div>
             </DownloadWrapper>
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I appreciate all your help, but really in this case I cannot do it like this. To the best of your knowledge, there is no way to implement it like I'm trying to? I'm trying to inject children dynamically to an element and render it as a component, I'm sure there is a way to do this

Comment: There is no difference between `const MyButton = <Button size='large'/>` and what i'm doing now

Comment: Please link to the documentation of the libray you are using so I can show some working examples.

Comment: Yes there's a big difference. I want to pass Button (or whatever element), and inject its children later in the future, in the way you are doing it, you must do it together at one point.

Comment: The third party package React PDF renderer does accept children, but I want to pass them in another point in time after receiving the component WITHOUT children

Comment: @sir-haver: *"after receiving the component WITHOUT children"* - Perhaps you can clarify that a bit more in a running [mcve] (even if it has an error because the attempt doesn't work yet) which demonstrates what you're trying to accomplish?  It's sounding increasingly likely that understanding the overall goal here would allow us to take a step back from the specific thing you're trying to describe and arrive at a solution to the actual functionality you need to achieve.  It seems that we're struggling to understand the overall goal here.

Comment: @David and 0stone0 thank you I updated my code to explain exactly what I'm trying to achieve can you please tell me if it's detailed enough? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for your help that's also a good idea, I would still be very happy to know about a way to do it as I originally intended also for better understanding of React, so I'll leave the question open, thanks again!

Comment: Don't think there is a better way to inject the children later, since if you define a variable with the component, cloning the component (if possible) is way more inefficient than using a wrapper function.